# Road class restriction of OSM data

Tags: openstreetmap, route, astar

I'm manipulating an OSM dataset of Chicago to find the optimal path for heavy duty vehicles. Are there some roads restrictions? Which class is not allowed for heavy vehicles?

These are road classes of the OSM map:

```
"secondary"
"motorway"
"trunk_link"
"tertiary"
"unclassified"
"secondary_link"
"tertiary_link"
"trunk"
"primary"
"residential"
"primary_link"
"motorway_link"
```

I asked to get a dataset of road restriction [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13214/restricted-and-allowed-roads-for-heavy-duties-in-chicago/13224#13224) and I didn't get a pertinent answer.

Comment: you will have to catergorise them yourself, https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway (UK/Europe classification is slightly different to US/Canada)

Comment: A few things. OSM data is rarely 'perfect', so keep that in mind. Rather then figuring out where it IS allowed, you'll find OSM data has more info on where restrictions apply.  https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:maxweight seems like one of the tags to eliminate paths you can take.

Comment: In addition, not too many weight restricitons appear to be mapped: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/Brc

Comment: By looking at the OSM data from Chicago it comes mostly from imported Tiger data. There are very few additional tags. Each road class per se probably allows driving also with heavy vehicles. It looks like OSM data needs to be improved for your purposes. If you live there you can go out with your friends and start mapping but it is a big city.

Comment: @user30184 thank you for commenting, I don't live there and I don't have any idea of chicago's roads.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. @TimCouwelier I don't have the maxweight tag in my dataset have you an idea of how can I add this tag?